# How to export JSON to JSP?

Tags: json, jsp

I'm having an issue with `JSON` and `JSP`. My `Java` code creates a `JSON` from a `map`, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/internationalWAExpose", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String exposeWAData(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, WebAnalyticsDataValue> ajaxDataMap = new HashMap<>();
    WAGlobalDataHandler globalHandler = WebAnalyticsFactory.getHandler(WAGlobalDataHandler.class);
    globalHandler.setGlobalData(request, "Home", "Content");
    ajaxDataMap.putAll(globalHandler.getDataMap());

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    ajaxDataMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        try {
            json.put(k, v);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return json.toString();
}
```

And I need to get the `JSON` on a `JSP` to be exposed in the elements section.
So far, I managed to set it in a JS with an `Ajax` call, but it shows on the console, rather than in the elements section.

```
AAUI.ajaxRequest({
    url: '/home/ajax/internationalWAExpose',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 50000,
    onSuccess: function onSuccess(jsonResponse, textStatus) {
        var webAnalyticsData = [];
        for (var x in jsonResponse) {
            webAnalyticsData.push(new KeyValueObject(x, jsonResponse[x]));
        }
        waTealiumUtils.reportEvent(webAnalyticsData, "view");
    },
    onError: function onError() {
    },
    onComplete: function onComplete() {
    }
})
```

Any ideas? Be advised, I'm quite a newbie to `JS` and `JSP`.

Comment: Because the rest looks ok, the problem seems to be in `waTealiumUtils.reportEvent(webAnalyticsData, "view");`, so you have to investigate this function. Or show its code, too.

Comment: Function. 

`var waTealiumUtils = {
    reportEvent : function(waArray,type){
        try {
            var utagValues={};
            for(var i=0;i<waArray.length;i++) {
                utagValues[waArray[i].key]=  waArray[i].value;
            }
            if(type == "view" && utag.view !== 'undefined') {
                utag.view(utagValues);
            }  else if (type == "click" && utag.link !== 'undefined'){
                utag.link(utagValues);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            //Fail quietly
        }
    }`

Comment: There is also a reportJsonEvent method: `reportJsonEvent : function (jsonObject, type) {
        try {
            if(type == "view" && utag.view !== 'undefined') {
                utag.view(jsonObject);
            }  else if (type == "click" && utag.link !== 'undefined'){
               utag.link(jsonObject);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            //Fail quietly
        }`

Perhaps I could use this one, modifying the Ajax call?